# Refactoring messes up mutable borrow - why?

Tags: rust, lifetime

I'm trying to understand why does the following refactoring result in an error, even though it should effectively have the same behaviour:

Before:

```rust
fn req_handler(req: &mut Request) -> IronResult<Response> {
    let pool = req.get::<Read<Database>>().ok().expect("database component not initialised");
    let connection = pool.get().unwrap();

    let maybe_id = req.extensions.get::<Router>().unwrap().find("id");
    ...
```

After:

```rust
pub fn get_pool_connection<'a, 'b, 'c>(req: &'a mut Request<'b, 'c>) -> PooledConnection<'a, PostgresConnectionManager> {
    let pool = req.get_ref::<Read<Database>>().ok().expect("database component not initialised");
    pool.get().unwrap()
}
fn req_handler(req: &mut Request) -> IronResult<Response> {
    let connection = get_pool_connection(req);
    let maybe_id = req.extensions.get::<Router>().unwrap().find("id");
```

This results in error:

```
src/main.rs:64:20: 64:34 error: cannot borrow `req.extensions` as immutable because `*req` is also borrowed as mutable
src/main.rs:64     let maybe_id = req.extensions.get::<Router>().unwrap().find("id");
                                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
src/main.rs:62:42: 62:45 note: previous borrow of `*req` occurs here; the mutable borrow prevents subsequent moves, borrows, or modification of `*req` until the borrow ends
src/main.rs:62     let connection = get_pool_connection(req);
                                                        ^~~
src/main.rs:76:2: 76:2 note: previous borrow ends here
src/main.rs:61 fn req_handler(req: &mut Request) -> IronResult<Response> {
...
src/main.rs:76 }
```

So the problem is that `get_pool_connection` borrows the request and gives back `connection` which prevents further `req` use. But why does this happen? `req` is guaranteed to use at least the same lifetime as the returned `PooledConnection`. It's not moved either, it was just passed as `&mut`. So what prevents the request from being used?

And why does the error say that `*req` was borrowed, when both local `req` and the function parameter are references?

(relevant docs: [Request](http://ironframework.io/doc/iron/request/struct.Request.html), [Pool](https://sfackler.github.io/r2d2/doc/r2d2/struct.Pool.html))

Comment: The error says that `*req` is borrowed exactly because `req` is a reference. After all, you usually borrow some owned data the reference points at, not the reference itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's actually exactly the meaning of the lifetime annotations. If you have a function having this prototype:

```
fn get_bar<'a>(&'a Foo) -> Bar<'a> { ... }
```

It means that the `Bar` object returned owns a lifetime tied to the one of the `Foo` object. As a consequence:

- the `Bar` objects borrows the `Foo` object as long as it is alive
- the `Bar` object is not allowed to outlive the `Foo` object.

In your case, `connection` is of type `PooledConnection<'a, ...>`, where `'a` is the lifetime defined in `&'a mut req`, it thus is considered as a mutable borrow of `req`.

It worked before the refactoring, because the lifetime of `connection` is actually linked to the lifetime of `pool`, which didn't borrow `req` as it does not hold any lifetime parameter.

As your refactoring forces `connection` to borrow `req`, which was not needed before, maybe it is not an appropriate refactoring.

Comment: Is there any way to return the connection and make the refactoring work? Or would I have to return the pool too in that case?

Comment: You will have a hard time returning both the pool and the connection, as their lifetimes are tied together. In this precise case of refactoring only two lines of code into a function, I don't see any better solution than not refactoring.